# How can I generate sql inserts from pipe delimited data?

Tags: haskell

I've got a small project that I would like to attempt to do in
Haskell. Given a set of delimited data in the following format:

1|Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope|1977|Action,Sci-Fi|George Lucas
2|Titanic|1997|Drama,History,Romance|James Cameron

In Haskell, how can I generate sql insert statements in this format?

insert into table values(1,"Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope",1977","Action,Sci-Fi","George Lucas",0);
insert into table values(2,"Titanic",1997,"Drama,History,Romance","James Cameron",0);

To simplify the problem, let's allow for a parameter to tell which
columns are text or numeric. (e.g. 0,1,0,1,1)

Here's a solution in Perl.  Now I'd like to add Haskell to my toolkit.

```
my @ctypes=qw/0 1 0 1 1/;

while(<>) {
  chop;
  @F=split('\|', $_);
  print "insert into table values(";
  foreach my $col (@F) {
    my $type=shift(@ctypes);
    print ($type == 1 ? '"'.$col.'"' : $col);
    print ",";
  }

  print "0);\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import Control.Arrow
import Data.List

main :: IO ()
main = interact $ unlines . map (makeInsert . splitOn '|') . lines

splitOn :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitOn delim = unfoldr (fmap break') . return
  where break' = second (stripPrefix [delim]) . break (== delim)

makeInsert :: [String] -> String
makeInsert parts = "insert into table values(" ++ intercalate "," values ++ ");"
  where values = zipWith ($) [id, show, id, show, show] parts ++ ["0"]
```

although you might want to use [`Data.List.Split.splitOn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/latest/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html#v%3asplitOn) instead of writing your own, and `show` isn't necessarily the right way to quote strings.

Answer (score 3):

Read in the data, split at the pipe symbols, escape all your values correctly, and use string concatenation to build up your query.

Comment: Summary answer, but a +1 for "escape all your values correctly". http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: You shouldn't really escape the values at all. Instead you should use a `?` placeholder, and provide the actual value to the database library separately.

Comment: You are right. But the question was specifically about insert statements.

Comment: Other than tagging the question Haskell, and saying, "In Haskell..." a few times, how can I convey that I would like the problem solved in Haskell?  No need to escape correctly, the answer simply needs to work for the given data.